# Getting return value of COM object that uses pass-by-reference

Tags: python, matlab, com

I have a niche program (targeted to a small specific industry) that has a COM server for interacting with it. This COM server works fine when called from VBA, but I have not been able to get it to work with MATLAB or Python. Any function that returns a value just errors out, but I can still use methods that don't pass anything back, like load a file.

I think the problem is that all of the methods require pass-by-reference. All of the methods instead pass back an error number as the output for every method (0 if no error, otherwise some value). For example, in VBA you could use the method `err = GetFileName(fileName)`. The `fileName` variable can be empty but after the method call it is set to the name of the file and `err` contains the error number.

When I attempt to call any method that passes back something in addition to the error number in MATLAB or Python, I get a type mismatch or missing parameter error `Error: Type mismatch, argument 1`. The methodsview function in MATLAB returned the methods below. I don't really understand what a MATLAB array type is because passing an empty array still gives an error.

Here is an example of how I attempt this:

```
api = actxserver('ProgID')
ans = invoke(api,"methodname")
% this will give a missing parameter error
ans = invoke(api,"methodname",[])
% this will give a mismatch error for input 1 (the empty array)
[ans ans2] = invoke(api,"methodname",[])
% also a mismatch error for input 1
[ans ans2] = invoke(api,"methodname")
% missing parameter error
```

It doesn't change anything I make the empty array a variable or try to create a function handle that just returns a value.

```
f = @(a) a
```

I have tried [this](https://www.mathworks.com/help/compiler_sdk/dotnet/object-passing-by-reference.html#bswl58u-2) but it says MWObjectArray doesn't exist.

[coder.ref](https://www.mathworks.com/help/simulink/slref/coder.ref.html) appears to only be for C++ stuff.

[This](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_external/passing-net-data-in-matlab.html) doesn't seem to have a MATLAB array data type.

[This](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_external/using-methods.html) says that pass-by-reference can be done by using multiple output variables, but I still get a type mismatch or missing parameter error.

Has anyone run into a similar issue? Is there a way to get more information on what exact type is needed when a type mismatch error is returned?

[image: MATLABmethodview]

Comment: I would expect 2 output arguments and no input when called from MATLAB, but lacking MATLAB and Windows on the same system, I can't try it.

Comment: How is your server written? Do you have some reproducing code?

Comment: @Daniel I have tried 2 output arguments, still doesn't work

Comment: @SimonMourier I added some psuedocode to the question

Comment: I meant code for the server, not the client. It seems it's the server that has issues.

Comment: @SimonMourier I'm not really sure how to see that. This is an application built by another company I use that has the ability to be controlled by ActiveX. Their help document shows the methods available and they work in VBA but not MATLAB or Python.

Comment: Ok, it wasn't clear you were not developing the server. You should contact them then. It's easy to write a bad server.